# Formula of ideal diode for dc load line analysis

Tags: voltage, diodes, dc

There is a formula when solving diode circuits with load line analysis which is not the Shockley diode equation but looks like it and it is exponential this is what i can remember about it I am wondering if anybody knows it

Comment: This is one long rambling line that asks for mountains of effort in reply. The site is not for free personal tutoring and you can quite easily research this on the internet. Please edit your question and detail you already know, show all that you have discovered for yourself on the subject.

Comment: Is it just the ideal diode equation without the "-1" part? That should be reasonably accurate in forward bias.

Answer (score 1):

### My simple load-line approximate model depends on the type and power rating of the diode.

**When in doubt, use the datasheet.**

e.g. Si threshold at 1mA, Vth=600 mV  (+20%/-5%) @ 25’C. series Rs typically k~ 0.25 to 1 over Pmax **rating** @ Tj=25’C with Pd derating above Tj= 25’C.

**But this is the widest tolerance of all production tolerances and only shows as Vf typ and Max for all diodes including most LEDs.**  Tolerances like hFE & Vce(Sat) in BJT's and Rs for diodes can be computed as +/-50% which improves with production equipment and better quality sources and new technology (e.g. Diodes Inc) and binning (e.g. Rohm).

Although Vth has a NTC of -2.4 mV/‘C , Rs also reduces towards a constant value due to bulk resistance with rising current and self-heating. I.e.linear R load-line above asymptote threshold or Vth at 10% of rated current.

### My Rule of Thumb

(well above knee)

\$V_f = V_{th} + I_f*R_S ~~~~...R_S[Ω]=  \dfrac{k}{P_{max} [W]}\$)

e.g.

The purpose of these examples is to approximate the one significant figure of the constant \$k\$ above ( due to tolerances)

From the typical 25’C **Vf/If log-lin curves**; (not worst max in tables)

```
p/n.       Vth(1mA) Vf(10mA),  Vf(100mA) Vf(1A) . Pd max.  
==========  =======  =======   ========   ======  =======
BAS16L     610 mV    720 mV     910 mV     ~>=2V   225 mW   
 3 Ω        thus for Vf(100mA)= 910 mV,   Rs=3Ω =(Vf-Vth)/If=300mV/100mA   
 so k ~ 0.7                              k = 3 Ω * 225 mW

1N4005         x     600mV      735 mV     960 mV  1.6W ,  1.5V @ 10A pulse   
 0.36 Ω                 thus for Vf(1 A) = 960 mV, Rs=360 mΩ =  360mV/1A
 so k ~ 0.6                            k = 0.36 Ω * 1.6W  

NSR0230M2T5G 200 mV  275 mV     360 mV      n/a    167 mW   
 1.6  Ω         thus for Vf(100mA)= 360 mV, Rs=1.6 Ω=(Vf-Vth)/If=160mV/100mA        
 so k ~ 0.3                               k = 1.6 Ω * .167W = 0.267

D4600U45X172XPSA1 (hockey puck) 1.35V @ 1000 Amps, 1.75V @ 2000 A, 2.05V @ 3000 A   Vf=1.9V typ @ 2500A = 4750 W 
 0.35 mΩ        thus for slope resistance Rs= (2.05V-1.35)/(3000A-1000A)= 0.35 mΩ 
 so k ~ 1.7                               k = 0.35 mΩ @ 4.75kW = 1.67
```

This demonstrates the linear quality of the load line is related to **rated power Pd** and size of the junction which affects the bulk resistance.  **This is useful as a figure of merit to estimate incremental load-line resistance, Rs** , but tolerances are large and cooling design can improve additional variances.